# How to move a DataTable row to the first position of its DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, dataset

I want to get a specific row on an asp.net DataTable and move it to be the first one onto this DataTable base on a column `column1` value. My Datatable `dt1` is populated via a DB query and the value to search is via another query from another DB so I don't know the value to search at the `dt1 select` time.

```
// I use this variable to search into
// DataTable
string valueToSearch = "some value";
```

So I need to search the value `some value` into my DataTable in the column `column1`. and then move the entire row to the first position.

Thank you.

Comment: How is this DataTable populated?

Comment: @WonkotheSane through a DataBase query. Figure I have `column1` with string values.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

We have to clone the row data before:

```
            DataRow[] dr = dtable.Select("column1 ='" + valueToSearch +"'");
            DataRow newRow = dtable.NewRow();
            // We "clone" the row
            newRow.ItemArray = dr[0].ItemArray;
            // We remove the old and insert the new
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(dr[0]);
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to test the performance on this, but one way to do this is in the query itself.  Get the rows that you want at the top first, and combine that with the rest of the rows.

Since I know nothing of your database, here is a generic way to do this:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM MyTable
WHERE Column1 = 'some value'

UNION

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM MyTable
WHERE Column1 <> 'some value'
```

Comment: I can't do it because the sources of the datatable and the value to search are different, so I don't know the value to search at query time.

Comment: In that case, I think you should edit your question to put in more details.  How is the datatable populated (including the binding), how is 'some value' entered as a filter, etc.  Right now, we're all guessing at your design.

Answer (score -1):

If the column has only one record for the searched value than try this

```
DataRow[] dr = dtEmp.Select("column1 ='" + valueToSearch +"'");
myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr[0], 0);
```

Comment: I cannot insert it because it already belongs to this datatable, so i'd need to remove prevously.

Comment: Take a look at this. you dont need to delete the row and insert it again if it works. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/312545/A-method-to-move-rows-within-a-DataTable